# Set cookie with duplicated attribute with different values

Tags: cookies, samesite

Let's say I try to set a cookie with 2 (or more!) `SameSite` attributes with different values, like:

```
CookienName=CookieValue; secure; SameSite=None; SameSite=Lax
```

**Which value will be taken into account?**

I've done some tests in Chrome 116 and I see that the last value is always taken into account:

| Attributes in Set-Cookie | Resulting Value |
| --- | --- |
| ...; SameSite=None; SameSite=Lax | Lax |
| ...; SameSite=Lax; SameSite=None | None |
| ...; SameSite=Strict; SameSite=None | None |

But I wonder if this behaviour is defined somewhere in the specification or if it is browser specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the `SameSite` attribute is not yet mentioned there, the specification for receiving cookies in [RFC 6265](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc6265.html#storage-model) states that only the last attribute value is stored if there are several, for example:

> If the cookie-attribute-list contains an attribute with an attribute-name of "Domain":
> Let the domain-attribute be the attribute-value of the *last* attribute in the cookie-attribute-list with an attribute-name of "Domain".